Does S7-1500 support OpcUA transfer subscription?
As the title of the question, does the Siemens S7-1500 PLC controller support the OpcUA transfer subscription service? If not, what is the reason for not supporting this service?
Search a bit online, feel it might not support it, but could not find a document/link with clear answer.

Your title says "S7", in your question it says "S5".

updated the question.

Register for support here: https://support.industry.siemens.com/
Then create a support ticket asking the above question.  It's free.  Please post your answer to Stack Exchange so we can rate you.
